# Как отследить развертывание скрипта

Tags: php, zend-framework

Не судите строго, я только стажируюсь. В данный момент развернул у себя локально веб приложение, достаточно сложное, построено на фрейворке Zend Framework. Требуется изменить его работу, но не могу понять где ковырять. Приложение MVC. т.е. понятно что нужно найти контроллер там запилить и проверить вьюшку, но их тут далеко не один... Может есть способ как отследить какие скрипты запускались и что вызывалось во время отображения страницы?

Comment: вы можете почитать документацию по фреймворку, там обычно пишут как именно все работает. так же можете включить максимальное логирование и изучить лог. и добавьте информацию о фреймворке в вопрос.

Comment: @ Mikhail Vaysma, логированием можно отследить к каким файлам было обращение?

Comment: это зависит от фреймворка. но часто при включении максимального лога можно увидеть много. но я бы рекомендовал просто почитать документацию.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, это долго. хотя , безусловно, я собираюсь это сделать. а багтрекер не несет в себе такой функции? ни разу не пользовался, поэтому не представляю что это.

Comment: баг-трекер - это система работы с ошибками. но вероятно вы спрашивали про дебагер.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ну да.